# Failed to start Light Display Manager

Tags: boot, update, gui, lightdm

[image]I've been getting this error a few times but somehow was able to get through it by plugging in the hdmi cable (I use vnc).  But now the I get this error even when I use the HDMI cable.

I tried installing the `lightdm` packages again and it says nothing new is installed.

When I try `sudo apt-get update` or `upgrade`, it says

> Error: Timeout was reached

and the same thing happens when I try reinstalling `lightdm`.

One additional minor thing is that the bluetooth service is also unavailable.

I tried looking for help on the internet but it seems that no one has solved this problem, so they just make a new sd, but I prefer not to since it takes time and I have to start from the beginning again.

What I've been doing recently was I was trying to make a face-detection sentry gun using `openCv`.  I have little to no experience in using linux and I'm new to using the PI.   Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Also, I am now getting a segmentation error on some sudo commands.